# Tab autocomplete path vim

Tags: autocomplete, tab-completion

Is there a way to auto complete a path in vim as in /v [tab] -> /var/ in the command line

I've tested ctrl x ctrl f, but it is not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: In what way ctrl x ctrl f isn't appropriate for your needs?

Comment: off topic: why are you using backtics instead of quotes?

Comment: on topic: I can just type `:e /v[tab]` to get `:e /var/` in the command line. It should be working with tab as long as your command (`:e` in this case) is relevant.

Comment: I want to use it in insert mode since I do a lot of scripting, maybe ctrl x ctrl f works fine and I just haven't got the hang of it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ctrl-X Ctrl-F can be used in insert mode as well. I think it does just what you want.

If you want to complete everything with tab (filename completion as well as onmicompletion and stuff) I suggest the following vim plugin: "neocomplcache". It features many autocompletion options and can be highly customized. That makes it also a bit complex to configure, however.

Here is the link to the plugin github page: https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache.